# Node Project is not running on remote server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

No problem when running locally but when running on server getting the following error

```
/dk/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/add_user.js:16
        this.options = options ?? {};
                                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
```

When npm install getting some warnings like

```
Unsupported engine {
   package: 'dk@1.0.0',
   required: { node: '>=14.0.0', npm: '>=7.0.0' },
   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
 }
 Unsupported engine {
   package: 'bson@5.4.0',
   required: { node: '>=14.20.1' },
   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
 }
 Unsupported engine {
   package: 'mongodb@5.7.0',
   required: { node: '>=14.20.1' },
   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
 }
 Unsupported engine {
   package: 'mongoose@7.4.3',
   required: { node: '>=14.20.1' },
   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
 }
 Unsupported engine {
   package: 'mquery@5.0.0',
   required: { node: '>=14.0.0' },
   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
 }
```

Here it saying that my current version is v12.22.9 But node -v gives :   v18.17.1

I've tried reinstalling node, npm, mongodb and upgrading mongoose but still have this issue. any help would be helpful

Comment: The error is because the version of node being used does not support [Nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) which requires Node v14.0 or greater. Are you using [npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) to run different versions of node possibly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yarn --ignore-engines` as your `build command` on your remote server.